# Firetop Mountain opening moves

Tags: firetop-mountain

I really love [Firetop Mountain](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/index.html) , but I struggle to understand and play first few moves, so I often end up playing them a bit random.

I'd like to understand if there is a tried and tested approach to the first moves, as they are important to set the tone of the game (i.e. one player attacking and the other defending until he can turn the table).
Can anybody give me some good hint?

Answer (score 3):

There are some classical openings, as PD for duels. But anyway, the best behavior is to not draw your moves as you have planned them before the game start, but instead react quickly as you see what other players are doing. The newbie mistake is to keep the plan unchanged. You really have to change your mind every turn if necessary. That means even break looooong spells. And that's paintful, i know.

So to answer your question, as an old player, yes, I almost choose my first two gestures randomly. Using classical opening means having each time almost the same game for the 8 first rounds. And that's annoying - to me. And when I say "at random", understand that I have one hand with one of the protecting spells and one starting an attack spell.

Comment: Well... a PD start to me looks like a Charm person (or Summon Ogre) + Confusion (or Amnesia) start: all attacking spells, tendencially... unless you plan to cast them on yourself in order to cancel another enchantment cast on you by your opponent...